# SQL Query in DB2

Tags: db2

I have a table and below are examples of the columns I am interested in and how the data looks

Ref   | Date
Ref 1 | 2016-05-01
Ref 1 | 2016-05-01
Ref 2 | 2017-02-20
Ref 2 | 2017-02-20
Ref 2 | 2017-02-20
Ref 2 | 2015-12-10

I want a query that will return a count of all references and the number of instances of that duplicate date there are. So for the above it should return

Ref 1 | 2016-05-01 | Count 2
Ref 2 | 2017-02-20 | Count 3
Ref 2 | 2015-12-10 | Count 1

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by the columns you want to be unique and then you can use aggregate functions (like `count()`) which apply to each group

```
select ref, date, count(*)
from your_table
group by ref, date
having count(*) > 10
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Always seems to simple when you see the answer. Thanks for a lot for this. Will mark as correct when it allows me.

Comment: What would I add to the query if I wanted to only display the ones where the count number is greater than say 10?

Comment: Updated the answer. `having` is the `where` clause for group conditions

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I added the following which fixed that. Having COUNT(*) > 10